# How to select elements that are dynamically generated through a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension and every time a page loads, I need to extract all the links on the page. To do this I use jQuery:

```js
let tempElements = $('a')
let tempElementsContent = tempElements.contents()
```

This extracts all links except those that are generated dynamically, like due to an onClick event. Since I cannot trigger the event or listen to it, how do I extract the links.

An example is the `sign-out` link on https://www.youtube.com. Here, only when you click on your account does the link appear. How can I extract this link (https://www.youtube.com/logout) when the page loads?

Comment: *"How can I extract this link (`https://www.youtube.com/logout`) when the page loads?"* I don't think you can, if it really doesn't exist until you click your account. But you could see when it was added, with a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). [This search](/search?q=chrome+extension+mutationobserver) suggests that they do work in Chrome extensions.

Comment: Hmm. But using MutationObserver, the user has to click on "Your account", right? Just to make sure, there isn't a way in which I can trigger the action to get links? (Can't be specific to youtube, has to work on all sites)

Comment: You might be able to simulate the click, but you'd have to know that clicking that specific element will reveal links that you want to harvest.